# Is the usage of Scalariform as an embedded library considered abandoned?

Tags: scala, scala-2.11, scalariform

I had been using Scalariform in a project I upgraded to Scala 2.11. In doing so, I discovered that Scalariform does not appear to have an artifact published for 2.11 in any of the usual [places](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/scalariform/). This makes the usual sbt cross-version dependency unhappy.

As 2.11 has been out for a while already, this has me questioning if the usage of Scalariform as an embedded library should be considered abandoned? Has the community moved on to an alternative I just don't know about?

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly good Stack Overflow question, but it's a good question, and [here's a recent partial answer](https://twitter.com/mattrusselluk/status/560189467005550593).

Answer (score 3):

Scalafmt is an alternative code formatter that does compile to 2.11 and can be used as an embedded library. An up-to-date usage example is here https://olafurpg.github.io/scalafmt/#Standalonelibrary

Comment: Nice. More accurate than my answer. +1

Comment: You have the rep to comment now... I've removed the bit about that, but if there is info that needs to be corrected on another post, please do comment on it!

Comment: Yay, my first SO comment! Thank you @Mogsdad for the edit.

Comment: I have deleted my answer, as requested.